# How to use child route inside default route by using exact

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

Here is my code

```
<Route path='/' component ={component}>
 <Route path='/login' component = {login}/>
 <Route path='/signup' component = {signUp}/>
</Route>
<Route exact path = '/newPath' component = {NewComponent} />
```

Problem is if I am calling login and signup I want to call '/' also.
but when I want to call '/newPath' i don't want to use '/'. but how to avoid '/' without using the exact keyword. because when I use the exact word with '/' it can not be called in login and signup.

Comment: If you write `<Route exact path='/newPath' component={NewComponent} />` before the `<Route path='/' ... />`, this should work. `path="/"` will match every url, so it should be at the end of your routes declaration

Comment: But this solution doesnot work for child routes. It is neither opening login component or signup component

Comment: @chauhanamit, which version of react-router are you using

Comment: I am using react-router v4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can:

```js
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
      <Route path="/auth" component={Auth} />
      <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} />
      ...
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

And inside your Auth: have another router with login and signup components